Screening layer problem when the electrodes were made by placing a few layers of metal on top of a semiconductor monolayer
The electrodes were made by placing a few layers of metal on top of a semicondutor monolayer. The scattering region was constructed by adding an extended region of metal electrodes to the semiconductor region, so that the wave function and potential change smoothly from
the electrodes to semiconductor. The extended region (screening layer) had been tested from
around 0.4 nm to 1.2 nm, transiesta still refused to convergence when screening layer was set to 1.2 nm. Parts of the output is shown in the following:
transiesta: Charge distribution, target =   5580.00000
Total charge                  [Q]  :   5580.00000
Device                        [D]  :   2881.64456
Left                          [E1] :  1333.67278
Left                 / device [C1] :    10.34306
Right                         [E2] :  1333.67028
Right                / device [C2] :    10.33452
Other                         [O]  :     10.33480
Excess charge                [dQ]  :  2.00089E-11

ts-q:         D        E1        C1        E2        C2         dQ
ts-q:  2209.858  1333.673    10.732  1333.670    10.602 -0.671E+03
ts-Vha:  0.48651141E+03 eV

········

ts-scf:  197  2770090.894812  2770090.894812  2770090.894812  0.000000 -3.870737  0.000000
ts-q:         D        E1        C1        E2        C2         dQ
ts-q:     0.096  1333.673    -0.125  1333.670    -0.106 -0.290E+04
ts-Vha:  0.25579570E+04 eV
ts-scf:  198  2770090.894812  2770090.894812  2770090.894812  0.000000 -3.870737  0.000000
ts-q:         D        E1        C1        E2        C2         dQ
ts-q:     0.096  1333.673    -0.125  1333.670    -0.106 -0.290E+04
ts-Vha:  0.25579570E+04 eV
ts-scf:  199  2770090.894812  2770090.894812  2770090.894812  0.000000 -3.870737  0.000000
ts-q:         D        E1        C1        E2        C2         dQ
ts-q:     0.096  1333.673    -0.125  1333.670    -0.106 -0.290E+04
ts-Vha:  0.25579570E+04 eV
ts-scf:  200  2770090.894812  2770090.894812  2770090.894812  0.000000 -3.870737  0.000000
SCF_NOT_CONV: SCF did not converge in maximum number of steps (required).
Geom step, scf iteration, dDmax, dHmax:    0   200      0.000000     0.000000
Geom step, scf iteration, dq:    0   200-2902.457019


In the output, dQ is too large, so it is the problem about the thickness of screening layer. However, I think 1.2 nm screening layer is quiet big. Therefore, I wonder if this kind of electrode needs a very large screening layer like a pure semiconductor electrode.

Have you read https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/11626/transiesta-with-siesta-version-4-1-5-not-converging

Yes, Sir, I have read the question.  Leaving the test of screening layers thickness aside, I will now try to use a smaller mixing parameter. And I will send feedback later.

The problem is finally solved by changing the pseudopotential file of Au from http://www.pseudo-dojo.org/ to https://departments.icmab.es/leem/SIESTA_MATERIAL/Databases/Pseudopotentials/periodictable-gga-abinit.html.
This turned out not to be a problem with the screening layer thickness or the input parameters, but purely a problem with the pseudopotential file.
